# D3 - how to select recently appended element

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am adding `circles` to a plot using D3.js, the circles need to be added with a timeout (for animation purpose) , so i am using `setTimeout`.

These circles also need to have `mouseover` and `click` event handlers registered on them, but i am not able to select the recently appended element for registering `on` listeners.

Here is the code:

```
 (salesDataToPlot.graphObj.eventData).forEach(

        function(d,i){


                setTimeout(
                  function(){
                    console.log(d.collectTime);

                    svg.append("circle")
                       .transition()
                       .duration(1000)

                       .attr("cx", function() { 
                        //console.log(new Date( d.collectTime.substr(0,10) ) );
                        return xScale(new Date( d.collectTime.substr(0,10) ) );
                       })
                      .attr("cy", function() {
                        //console.log(d.value);
                        return yScale( (d.value - min)/(max-min));
                      })
                      .attr("r", function() {
                        return 5;
                      })
                      .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
                      .attr("class","circle")
                      //.attr("ng-class","{ 'graphClass':!chartData.graphObj.showEventMarkers }")
                      .style("fill", eventStrokeColor)
                      ;
                }, 1000+ i*100);
      });
```

This code adds the circles with a timeout.

Now i am not sure where and how to add the code for `on` listeners like

```
.on("mouseover", function(d)
                      {
                        tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
                        tooltip.style("background-color",eventStrokeColor);
                        tooltip.html("<div style='color:black'>" + d.eventType + "</div>" + d.eventSentence);
                      })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add that when you crate the circle and append it to svg something like this:

```
 var ci = svg.append("circle")
                   .transition()
                   .duration(1000)
        .attr("fill", "aliceblue")
        .attr("r", 50)
        .attr("cx", cx)
        .attr("cy", cy);
ci
        .on("mouseover", function () {//adding listeners
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
        .on("mousemove", function () {
        return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
    })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

I have made a demo using setInterval with two circle 1st circle comes after 3 secs then 2nd comes after 6 secs

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/L3bpy6o4/2/)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It seems that you are attaching the listeners on the svg element and not on the circles

Comment: No gaurav. Cyril has attached listeners to the circles. Note that `append` function returns the appended elements itself.

Comment: ok.... looking at the code...it seemed like the listeners are attached to the svg element...but in reality it works well.

Comment: No gaurav,  in d3 _d3.select(".example_div svg")
        .append("svg:circle")_ returns me the circle DOM element to that i am assaigning the listeners

Comment: Ohk...i was getting errors like 'svg.transition().append().on()' is not a function, seems like the transition() function does not return a reference to the object

Comment: Oh ok Now i got the whole thing updated my answer and fiddle accordingly :) thanks for pointing that out.